# How to properly translate: "ドラゴンに食べられそうになったりと" in this context

Tags: translation

In the video game Recettear, you can buy a book with the title 仲良し姉妹の冒険記. The item description says the following:

> 世界中を旅しているという姉妹に密着した, ノンフィクション作品。ドラゴンに食べられそうになったりと，結構大変な事になってます。

The part I'm wondering about is this:

> ドラゴンに食べられそうになったりと

a.k.a

> [This book] makes you likely to be eaten by a dragon

Or

> [This book] is likely to be eaten by a dragon

Or what?

Comment: It seems to me the second sentence is describing the contents of the book. That being said, those who was almost eaten by a dragon are the sisters in the story.

Comment: I'm not sure how helpful it is to include the output of Google Translate here.

Comment: @snailboat - I thought this SE doesn't do straight translaion, from the tag note, but it seems I was mistaken, the Google Translate was to show some research

Comment: I think it's more important that we know what you understand so far, what specifically you're having trouble with, and so on.  That way we can help with your specific problem :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Keigh Rim pointed out, the description summarizes the contents of the book. The most notable event in the book is presumably when the sisters were almost eaten by a dragon.

The なったり part carries the implication that there are other events besides this one that are also described in the book. Since translation is also the art of selectively choosing the words that best carry the original meaning in a concise manner, I would translate that last sentence as:

> It tells of the sisters' trials, including the time they were nearly
>   eaten by a dragon.